# bubble always in front of the page

Tags: css

I have a slider which has a bubble window. Once I slide the slider, the bubble window will follow the location of the slider handler.The problem is above the slider there is a div which is used to display the header. So when the sliding is happening the bubble window was overlapped with the div above the slider in which the 1/3 portion the slider is hiding under the div. I used `z-index:100` for the bubble window to make it in front always once the sliding is happening. However, the bubble window is still under the div.please see image for your information. Any thought?

Bubble window container

```
.sliderAreaWithUnits { padding-left: 80px !important; padding-right:50px !important; padding-top: 30px !important; padding-bottom: 30px !important; position: relative;top: 0;left: 40;border-radius: 4px;}
```

Bubble window css

```
.bubbleWindow {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px; 
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 9px;
    background: transparent url('../Images/bubbleWithUnits.png') no-repeat ;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Header css

```
#headerTitle, .headerTitle {
    margin:0;
    color:@primary-text-color;
    padding:3;
    font:bold 16px Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.trigger #headerTitle {
    background:url('../../content/images/toggleArrowUp.png') no-repeat right;
    margin:0;
    height: 24px;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    font:bold 12px/24px Arial, Sans-Serif;
    color:@primary-text-color;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the bubble inside of another element with a z-index that is negative? That could be affecting it.

Comment: there is no z-index of the slider container please see updated code

Comment: Try giving the header actually a z-index (inferior to the bubble's) to have more control, you might have to set its position to relative to make its z-index to work, another thing that could work is changing in the code where is the bubble declared, before or after the header? switch it and test it, if you still can't get it to work you can post a link to the page so we can have a close look.

Comment: actually I put a z-index in the header's css but still no good.